# how to display the pdf file in iframe in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, iframe

The pdf does not show in iframe how to display the pdf file.

```
<iframe id="gen_view" src="" width="550" height="600"></iframe>
```

jquery  code

```
 $('#gen_view').attr("src", res.path);
```

The response for this file is here

```
{success: true, 
path: "/var/www/html/controlroom/storage/app/genrate_order
       /order_gen1591607597_.pdf"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#gen_view').attr("src", res.path);
```

Though for full browser support you should use a PDF javascript library such as https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js